# Rspec for checking whether a user is signed in or not in rails using devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, http-status-code-401

I have used devise gem in rails to authenticate the user.I need to write test cases for checking whether a use is signed in or not using Rspec. Only user signed in will have the rights to access the posts index page.It is perfectly for signed in user in the Rspec. But for signed out user i have tried few steps but I cant get it right.I have used Warden for simple authentication for testing purpose.My post controller spec for Signed out user is :

```html
describe "Unauthorized Access" do
    let(:user) {create(:user)}
    it "User tries to view post after Sign Out" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to have_http_status 401
    end
  end
```

Warden helper in the spec folder.

```html
RSpec.shared_context "api request global before and after hooks" do
  before(:each) do
    Warden.test_mode!
  end

  after(:each) do
    Warden.test_reset!
  end
end

RSpec.shared_context "api request authentication helper methods" do
  def sign_in(user)
    login_as(user, scope: :users)
  end

  def sign_out
    logout(:users)
  end
end
```

When I click sign out button it is redirected to the log in page and the rails log show the log like this

```html
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-05 11:33:10 +0530
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-05 11:33:10 +0530
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 69ms (Views: 67.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

But when I run the tests the rspec console showing error.

```html
expected the response to have status code 401 but it was 302

  0) PostsController Unauthorized Access User tries to view post after Sign Out
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status 401
       expected the response to have status code 401 but it was 302
     # ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:150:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Rspec log

```html
  (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
   (0.4ms)  begin transaction
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

Comment: Why are you expecting a status 401?

Comment: What are you trying to test, as per your test, your signing in the user and logging out and the response is obviously 200, because both the request is successful.

Comment: You should be testing for if you can view the post, and check if the user is logged in, if not, then check response status for 401. If you look at the log,  it says when you tried to list all the posts, when the user was not logged in it responded with `Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms`. You should be testing `posts` controller's `index` action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be testing in the following manner, make changes as per your requirement.

```
describe PostsController do

  describe "Index" do

    it "should allow user to view the list of posts" do
      get :index, {}, sign_in(@user)
      expect(response).to redirect_to(posts_path)
    end

    it "should not list posts if the user is not logged in" do
      get :index
      expect(response.status).to eq(302)
      expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_sessions_path)
    end
  end

end
```

Now what this test would do, when it runs it'll call your controller, assuming you have put `authenticate_user!`, it'll check if the user is logged in or not to view the list. Otherwise, the `action` will return 401.

You can try the following as well

```
  RSpec.describe "Posts", :type => :request do
    context "Index" do
      it 'should return 401 when not logged in' do
        sign_out user
        get posts_path
        expect(response).to have_http_status(302)
        follow_redirect!
        expect(response).to have_http_status(401)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: I have implemented your ans but it throwing error in test.

Comment: I dont want to use JSON so i have simply used like that

Comment: Is that the correct one for checking the unauthorized user

Comment: If a logged out user tries to go to post#index then it need should show 401 error right?

Comment: Yes, because, you're not passing in any user. So, when the request goes to the controller, put a pry and see if the request goes to your controller. It should fail.

Comment: pry means what ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179442/discussion-between-kedarnag-mukanahallipatna-and-praveen-r).